# Set Default PageSize of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, overriding

I am trying to override the PageSize property of the grid view to set the default value to 100, but when the code executes it takes the default value defined in the base class. Can anyone please help how can I set my default PageSize. I am extending the gridview control to customize according to my need.
Here is the code :

```
    [DefaultValue(100)]
    public override int PageSize
    {
        get
        {
            return base.PageSize;
        }
        set
        {
            base.PageSize = value;
        }
    }
```

Or should I try to set my default Page Sie in some overridden method like.

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.PageSize = 100;
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

Or

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.PageSize = 100;
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Comment: same problem here... @Evaldas solution does not seem to work - it seems overrides are not fired (yet some event's overrides are fired, indeed). I realize this post is old, did you get to a solution?

Answer (score 0):

DefaultValueAttribute is not meant for real default value, it is for VS designer only - first method will not work.
Quote from MSDN:

> A DefaultValueAttribute will not cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value in your code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Second and third methods will change PageSize to 100, but it will change for every gridview without possibility to change it in aspx page.

Best way I found it to work is to re-create the property:

```
private int _pageSize = 100;
public override int PageSize
{
    get
    {
        return this._pageSize;
    }
    set
    {
        this._pageSize = value;
    }
}
```

In that way the default PageSize will be 100 unless set otherwise per-gridview basis (in aspx PageSize="50" or cs gv.PageSize = 50 files).